# Cross Account Role for Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Trying to set up a cross account role from management account. The trust relationship has been set on management accounts as below

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<management_account_id>:role/LambdaCrossAccountRole"
      },
      "Action": "sts.AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

The lambda running from management account is Ec2Scheduler

However when the Lambda executes it complains

```
"Client Error:An  error occurred(AccessDenied)when calling the AssumRole operation:
User:arn:aws:sts:<managmentaccountid>:assumed-role/LambdaCrossAccountRole/Ec2Scheduler is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource> arn:aws:iam::<nonmanagementaccountid>:role/CrossAccountLambdaRole
```

There was a similar role for higher level admin tasks that was able to assume an admin level role in other accounts, however the trust relationship was set at
"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::<management_account_id>:root" and not on the Role itself as above.

Any ideas why this error is happening.

Comment: In addition to the AssumeRolePolicyDocument, the LambdaCrossAccountRole role's policy must allow the AssumeRole action to that role in the other account.  If you look at the existing role that's working, it probably has that allowed in some way

Comment: The reverse assumerole is not required, so no its not enabled on the other management role as well.

Comment: Yes, it is required.  IT's not the reverse, it's the corollary on the role permissions end.  Just because the AssumeRolePolicyDocument allows assumption , doesn't mean the principals allowed in that document themselves have the ability to AssumeRole.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html shows both parts being done

Comment: The other role that had been working on cross account access,  has full admin access, but its also an AWS managed role, that has execution role assume allowed as policy. Hence it was not visible in Trust Policy.

Comment: There's a typo in the role's trust policy: it should be `"sts:AssumeRole"` rather than `"sts.AssumeRole"`